# Pre-compiled Iperf 2.x binary for win32?

Tags: windows, iperf

I'd like to do some network testing on Windows using [Iperf](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/).  The latest on sourceforge appears to be 2.0.4.  However, it's only available as source to be compiled.  I attempted to do some google searching for a pre-compiled version, but all I could find were some links to 1.x stuff.

Admittedly, the 1.x version I found does seem to work and I could likely continue using it without issue.  But I've got the itch that says I need the latest version and setting up a build VM and dealing with inevitable compile issues doesn't sound like a whole lot of fun.  So I figured I'd ask here if anyone knows where to find pre-compiled Iperf 2.x binaries for Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Chris - No it won't.

And on that note, you can download the native compiled binary v2.0.4 [from here.](http://www.ivaturi.org/iperf/windows/compiled/2010/07/23/iperf-windows-compiled) (warning: shameless plug, if it even is that - links to my site).

Comment: Any chance that you could provide a 32-bit version?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just using Jperf (Java-based)?  It's at version 2.0.x and seems to have the same functionality as iperf: [**http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently compiled iperf on windows using cygwin
here's the output of `iperf -v`

> [iperf version 2.0.5 (08 Jul 2010)
>   pthreads]

Comment: How does that answer the question?